# Positive Linear Functionals on Von Neumann Algebras

Tags: analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\omega$ be a positive linear functional on $M$ which is a Von Neumann Algebra.  Suppose $\omega$ is completely additive (i.e. $\omega$ applied to a strongly convergent sum of mutually orthogonal projections is the same as the convergent complex valued sum of $\omega$ applied to the projections).  Then supposedly, $\omega$ is the pointwise convergent sum:

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \omega_{\xi_n} \text{ where } \omega_{\xi_n}(x)=\langle\xi_n, x(\xi_n)\rangle \qquad\forall x \in M$

Please prove this for me, but beware to not use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality in an incorrect way.  The reason I am without a proof is that the proof in a document I am reading is actually incorrect, and uses Cauchy Schwarz incorrectly.

Comment: What are the $\xi_n$?  Also, the right hand side does not seem to depend on $\omega$?

Comment: The $\xi_n$ are elements of the Hilbert space on which M acts, and they are chosen dependently on $\omega$

Comment: You can find a proof of this in Kadison and Ringrose, Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras II, Chapter 7.

Comment: I am not assuming that $\omega$ is a state.  Only that it is positive and completely additive.

Comment: Up to multiplication by a positive constant, a (nonzero) positive linear functional is a state. (Also, start a comment with  @UserName if you want to make sure someone will see it. As the asker of this question, you will receive an automatic notification of a comment, but no one else will.)

Comment: @Tom Cooney I have found it extremely difficult to jump into a book that I do not own, and therefore cannot even see all of due to the restrictiveness of google books. If I have to read something that uses someone else's notation that I can't find for legal reasons, the best I can hope for is just symbolically verifying something.  I'd rather have something a little less opaque so that my intuition can kick in, if that's possible to obtain from somewhere.

Comment: @Jeff What do you already know? Do you know that the completely additive states = the normal states (= $\sigma$-weakly continuous states = weak$^*$-continuous states)? (I include all these terms in case some are more familiar to you than others.) Do you know all normal states have a representation like in your question? If so, then the answer is 1. completely additive = normal, and 2. normal = desired representation. Point (2) is something you should find in any introductory book on von Neumann algebras.

Comment: @Jeff hopefully, you have access to one of the following. Book 1. Analysis Now by Pedersen: Section 4.6 (including exercises 4.6.8 and 4.6.9) plus the fact that normal states on $M \subset B(H)$ extend to normal states on $B(H)$. Book 2: Operator Algebras by Blackadar, Section III.2.1. (more complete if a little terse). Book 3: Theory of Operator Algebras 1 by Takesaki. Section II.2 (for point 2 of above comment) and then Corollary III.3.11 (but III.3.11 relies on quite a bit of other material).

Comment: Okay I will see what I can find in the "math library" at my school.  I don't know any of those things you mentioned, but I am aware they are true.  I am unwilling to use them because in my resource, the equivalence of 3 of the 4 statements you mentioned, plus the one I mentioned in this post, is proven.  The one implication I asked about in this post is the last one to establish this equivalence, but as far as I'm concerned right now none of these things are equivalent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise proof of this fact is given as Theorem 46.4 in Conway's book "A course in operator theory" (2000).

Comment: I actually ended up chasing through a not so concise proof that was obtained through a composition of Dixmier's book with other resources.